# Помогите с выводом значения из функции (поставить вывод в саму функцию r1 нельзя по данной мне задаче)

Tags: c++, функции

По задумке программа должна счет выполнять в отдельной функции(у меня это r3), но в независимости от вводимых значений выводится "1"

```
//Формула для решения задачи: А = F*L*cosa
//Задание №1.21 (Составить программу нахождения величины работы А, выполняемой силой F, дейстующей на тело под углом а на пути, длинной L)
    
    
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>


using namespace std;

 int r3(int f, int l, int a)
{
    int p;
    p = f * l * cos(a);
    return p;
}

int main(int p)
{
    system("color F5");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\tЛабараторная работа №1\n\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t     ЗАДАЧА:";
    cout << "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t     Задания №1.21";
    cout << "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t     Составить программу нахождения величины";
    cout << "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t     работы А, выполняемой силой F, дейстующей";
    cout << "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t     на тело под углом а на пути, длинной L\n";
    cout << "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t     Сноска:\n" << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t     Формула для решения задачи: А = F*L*cos(a)\n\n";
    cout << "Значения тестовой программы:\n F=10\n a=8\n L=1\n";
    int t = 10 * 8 * cos(1);
    cout << "Результат работы программы: " << t << "\n";

    int f, a, l;
    cout << "Ведите силу f: ";
    cin >> f;
    cout << "Ведите путь l: ";
    cin >> l;
    cout << "Ведите угол а: ";
    cin >> a;

    r3(f,l,a);

    cout << "---------------Результат работы программы: " << p; // По идее должна выводить число из функции r3
    cout << "\nПРОГРАММА ЗАВЕРШИЛА СВОЮ РАБОТУ, НАЖМИТЕ ЛЮБУЮ КНОПКУ И КОНСОЛЬ САМА ЗАКРОЕТСЯ\n";
}
```

Comment: две локальные переменные `p` в разных функциях. и их ничто не звязывает. результат функции нужно присвоить переменной `p = r3 ( f , l , a ) ;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не понял... Вам нужно

```
p = r3(f,l,a);
cout << "---------------Результат работы программы: " << p;
```

или, еще проще,

```
cout << "---------------Результат работы программы: " << r3(f,l,a);
```

Так?

Только учтите, что

```
int main(int p)
```

формально разрешено, но на самом деле у вас получается только запутывание...

Лучше

```
int main()
{
    ...

    int p = r3(f,l,a);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, все получилось когда сделал так "cout << "---------------Результат работы программы: " << r3(f,l,a);" и убрал из main "int p"